# How to disable button in nav component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a nav component where you can navigate back en for. But on a certain condition I want to disable the navigation buttons. So I try it like this:

```
<app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"
      [disabled]="status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"
      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
```

and this is the component:

```
export class EcheqProgressNavComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currentPage: number;
  @Input() totalPages: number;
  @Input() conditionals: { isFirst?: boolean; sending?: boolean };

  @Output() previous = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Output() next = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

But I get an error like this:

```
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'app-echeq-progress-nav'.
```

So what I have to fix?

Thank you

Oke, I try it like this:

```
<div class="echeq-progress-nav">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="echeq-progress-button echeq-progress-button-back"
    (click)="previous.emit()"
    [ngClass]="{ disabled: conditionals && (conditionals.isFirst || conditionals.sending) }"
    [disabled]="status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"

  >
    <span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="echeq-progress-pages">Vraag {{ currentPage }} / {{ totalPages }}</div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="echeq-progress-button echeq-progress-button-forward"
    (click)="next.emit()"
    [ngClass]="{ disabled: conditionals && conditionals.sending }"
    [disabled]="status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"
  >
    <span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I have it like this:

```
  <app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"

      [isbtnDisabled]="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"

      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
```

but here :

```
 <app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"

      [isbtnDisabled]="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"

      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
```

I dont have directly access with status

Comment: maybe `@Input() disabled: boolean;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a Input decorator in child's component.ts (echeq-progress-nav)

```
@Input() isBtnDisabled = false; // by default not disabled.
```

and bind this input to the relative button in the child-component's template:

```
<div class="echeq-progress-nav">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="echeq-progress-button echeq-progress-button-back"
    (click)="previous.emit()"
    [ngClass]="{ disabled: conditionals && (conditionals.isFirst || conditionals.sending) }"
    [disabled]="isBtnDisabled">
    <span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="echeq-progress-pages">Vraag {{ currentPage }} / {{ totalPages }}</div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="echeq-progress-button echeq-progress-button-forward"
    (click)="next.emit()"
    [ngClass]="{ disabled: conditionals && conditionals.sending }"
    [disabled]="isBtnDisabled">
    <span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

And in Parent Component, pass value to child-component.

```
<app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"
      [isBtnDisabled]="status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"
      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
```

Comment: Thank you I have it like this. But the button is still enabled: <button class="echeq-progress-button echeq-progress-button-forward" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="echeq-progress-button echeq-pr" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><span class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

Comment: No disabled attribute in your button.

Comment: But here in your comment there is no disabled attribute with button, that's why I asked you

Comment: Share the link.

Comment: I think the problem is with status.

Comment: Oh, I get this message: I cant go to chat

Comment: Debug your condition, for testing purpose you can set [isBtnDisabled]="true" in your parent, it will disable your btns in present in child

Comment: yes, oke, if do this:   [isbtnDisabled]="true" then the navigation buttons are disabled. But now for every status. And not only for status: EXPIRED. So that is the problem

Comment: Oh! That is for testing only buddy. Your condition/logic is wrong correct that, then btn will work as desired.

Comment: Yes of course. I understand that. But if I do this:   [isbtnDisabled]="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED" doesnt work

Comment: export enum  EcheqSubmissionStatus {
  SUBMITTED = 'Submitted',
  NEW = 'New',
  ACTIVE = 'Active',
  EXPIRED = 'Expired'
}

Comment: So for every one: new, active, it works , but not for Expired?? Dont understand

Comment: It works  by the other statuses. So I have to check here, why it doesn't work for expired. Thanks anyway for your effort.

Comment: your logic for expired might not be correct; condition for expired status is false else undefined.

Comment: Oke, but how to checkt that?

Comment: Hi, At the end it was the back end what needed to update the expired.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in ...component.ts

```
@Input() buttonIsDisabled: boolean
```

and bind this input to the relative button in the component template:

```
<button [disabled]="buttonIsDisabled">Some button in the template</button>
```

Comment: oke, thank you. But the condition is this:  [disabled]="status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED" so the button has not always been disabled. Only witht that condition